# why is this not writing (receiving) the correct number of Bytes?

Tags: c, file, ftp-client, vxworks

I receive data from an ftp socket connection. The connection seems tio be fine but for some reason, I don't get the correct nmumber of Bytes written to my destination file.
My source file has a size of `18735004 Bytes` and my algorithm writes `19713024 Bytes` to the file. Now can this be?
The code I have:

```
if (ftpXfer ("3.94.213.53", "**", "******", NULL,
             "RETR %s", "/home/ge", "ngfm.bin",
             &ctrlSock, &dataSock) == ERROR)
    return (ERROR);

pFile = fopen( "flash:/ngfm.bin", "wb" );
if ( pFile == NULL ) {
    printf("fopen() failed!\n");
    status = ERROR;
}

while ((nBytes = read (dataSock, buf, sizeof (buf))) > 0) {
    cnt++;
    n+=fwrite (buf , sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), pFile);
    if(cnt%100==0)
        printf(".");
}
fclose( pFile );
printf("%d Bytes written to flash:/ngfm.bin\n",n);
```

The screen output ended with:

```
19713024 Bytes writen to flash:/ngfm.bin
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ignoring the `nBytes` return value from `read()`, and instead always writing `sizeof buf` bytes to the output. That's wrong, for partial reads (where `nBytes` is less than `sizeof buf`) you are injecting junk into the written stream.

The write should of course use `nBytes`, too.

Also: the write can fail, and write *less* than you requested, so you need to loop it until you know that all bytes have been written, or you get an error from it.

Comment: yep, that makes sense! Thanks for prying open my eyes!

Comment: @cerr I/O is ... not perhaps hard in itself, but full of details, and it can fail.

Comment: well, I fixed it, compiled, uploaded the new image, ran a couple of tests and both succeeded - hence I assume it's fixed now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you aren't putting your FTP server in binary mode, and it's transferring in ascii. This replaces every \n with a \r\n sequence.

Additionally, unwind's reply is correct as well.

Comment: You can't see this in my code but ftpXfer() sets binary mode already. I can see `Request: TYPE I 50007 50007` in Wireshark, but I'll upvote your reply anyways!

Comment: I've been asked similar questions very often, and in most cases the problem was ascii transfer. So i didn't even look at the rest of the code when i didn't see you use binary :-/ Thank you for the upvote anyway.